# kubuntu 15.10 freezes intermittently - suspected compositor fault

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, freeze

I upgraded to Kubuntu 15.10 couple of days ago and experiencing weird freezes. When the freeze occurs, the screen is unresponsive but I can move the mouse. It occurs pretty randomly - when using the terminal, surfing etc. I went through the logs and haven't noticed anything.
I'm kinda suspecting problems with the compositor/cards but I'm not sure how to proceed.
Using a Dell inspiron with Kubuntu 15.10, Hybrid Nvidia-intel card (using nvidia 352 through driver manager)

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem with 16.04 and 16.10 - the box stopped responding to keyboard and mouse. Switching to Compositor settings to XRender seems to resolve it. 
System Settings -> Display and Monitor -> Compositor -> change Rendering backend to XRender

Comment: I actually think I experience it with every upgrade, and solve it through some variation of Nvidia driver choice

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, but without a Nvidia card. It's the Intel integrated GPU. Killing Xorg solves the problem, but it's obviously not a solution.